# Python Set Error Attributes as Null

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes, null

I have a particular file in which data is stored corresponding to certain labels. For eg:

> Name: John; Age: 14; Country: USA; etc

However, it is not consistent i.e the file contains something like

> Name: Kevin; Age: 15; etc

Notice that this data point contains some missing attributes like Country.

I wanted to set all the missing data as None. Specifically, something like:

```
try:
    (Do something with the available attributes)
except Exception,e:
    (Set all the attributes with error as null)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `set all the missing data as null` - set in what? A dictionary? How do you process the data already?

Comment: There is no `null` in python. Maybe you meant `None`

Comment: Yes I meant None. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try running your data through a function with default arguments, small hack:

```
def list_it(name = null, age = null, country = null):
    return [name, age, country]

for i in list_it():
    if i is not None:
    #do something
```

Comment: sorry, got a small brain fart when writing for loop. Did fix it!

Answer (score 0):

My ver:

```
keyword = [
    'Name',
    'Age',
    'Country',
]

buf = 'Name: Kevin; Age: 15;'

d = dict(item.strip().split(': ') for item in buf.split(';')[:-1])
for k in keyword:
    if k in d:
        # (Do something with the available attributes)
        pass
    else:
        # (Set all the attributes with error as null)
        d[k] = None

print(d)
# {'Country': None, 'Age': '15', 'Name': 'Kevin'}
```